# MySQL column type 'Double' - removes the digits after decimal

Tags: mysql, double

I need to insert values like below to a column with type Double

```
1.0
1.23
12.345
1234.5678
123456.1234567891
```

When I try to insert 123456.1234567891, it inserts only 123456.123456789 ('1' is missing in the end)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles have a precision of only [about 16 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) (52 bits).  My guess here is that the '1' on the end is outside the range of that precision and is getting lost.  Without moving to a different type, you will be unable to store it.

Comment: which type should I use?

Comment: You'd have to store it in the database as a string, unfortunately.  No other data type will store a decimal to the precision you require.

Comment: @Draco18s:  MySQL datatype **`DECIMAL(65,30)`** would be able to store up to 30 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @spencer7593 Doh! I'm a programmer not a data engineer. You'll have to forgive the lapse.